# Pandas dataframe: creating a new column that is a custom function using 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data set stored in a pandas DataFrame `dfX`:

```
A   B
1   2
4   6
7   9
```

I have a function that is:

```
def someThingSpecial(x,y)
  # z = do something special with x,y
  return z
```

I now want to create a new column in `df` that bears the computed z value

Looking at other SO examples, I've tried several variants including:

```
dfX['C'] = dfX.apply(lambda x: someThingSpecial(x=x['A'], y=x['B']), axis=1)
```

Which returns errors. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Might be useful to see what the errors are.

Comment: Good question. In trying to answer your point, I realized my lambda was correct - the error was in someThingSpecial and I got lost in the python error logs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work for me on v0.21. Take a look -

```
df

   A  B
0  1  2
1  4  6
2  7  9

def someThingSpecial(x,y):
     return x + y


df.apply(lambda x: someThingSpecial(x.A, x.B), 1)

0     3
1    10
2    16
dtype: int64
```

You might want to try upgrading your pandas version to the latest stable release (0.21 as of now).

---

Here's another option. You can vectorise your function.

```
v = np.vectorize(someThingSpecial)
```

`v` now accepts arrays, but operates on each pair of elements individually. Note that this just hides the loop, as apply does, but is much cleaner. Now, you can compute `C` as so -

```
df['C'] = v(df.A, df.B)
```

Comment: That works well, thank you! I like the elegance. As it turned out my original approach also worked - the error was in "somethingSpecial" but I changed to yours.

Comment: @user1361529 You're welcome. I've also found performance improvements with `vectorize`. Not sure what it does, but it's a real goto of mine.

Answer (score 3):

if your function only needs one column's value, then do this instead of coldspeed's answer:

```
dfX['A'].apply(your_func)
```

to store it:

```
dfX['C'] = dfX['A'].apply(your_func)
```